# Best method of associating file-extension with program

Tags: c#, file, file-association

I'm trying to associate multiple music-extensions with my program (mp3, wav etc etc)
and I've seen many different methods of doing this. But which one is the best?

Some methods seem to be quite hard (when editing registry etc. Something I've never done before) and some doesn't.

One that catched my eye though, was going to your project's properties (in Visual Studio) then "Publish" > "Options" > "File Associations" and then adding the associations there.

This method seemed to be the easiest so I tried it, But I can't seem to get it working.
Everytime I try to open .mp3's with my program, a messagebox pops up and tells me that

"The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program"

If anyone has associated filetypes using this method, I'd be happy if you knew what the cause of this problem might be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Windows 7` provides two commands for this purpose:

ASSOC associates a file extension to a filetype. You can also use it to display existing associations.

`FTYPE` defines or displays the "open" command to be executed for the give filetype.

**Example:**

```
ASSOC .pl=PerlSkript
FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
```

This makes it possible to call a `Perl` script like follows:

```
script.pl 1 2 3
```

Using the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you can also omit the extension when entering the command.

**Note:**
It is fairly easy to spoil your system by mis-using these commands. It might be less technical and less nerdy to use commands rather than tweaking the registry, but the risks are similar.